# How to escape command arguments in phpdbg console?

Tags: escaping, phpdbg

I try to call command in phpdbg console:

`argv --m=find --filters={"id":4}`

The result is:

```
[Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected identifier (command or function name), expecting # (pound sign) or digits (numbers)]
-->  STR_PARAM(argv=4)
-->  STR_PARAM(--m=find=8)
```

The problem is in colon character ":".
When i remove it from argument, all goes fine.
But i need it, to pass json data in arguments without translation.

`argv --m=find --filters={"id"\:4}` OR

`argv --m=find '--filters={"id":4}'` OR EVEN

`argv '--m=find --filters={"id":4}'`

PS. `argv` is user registered command in [.phpdbginit of Krakjoe](https://github.com/krakjoe/phpdbg/blob/master/.phpdbginit).

Comment: Thanks for that… we totally didn't think about that, I need to fix that bug...

Comment: @bwoebi, what is the right way for now to pass arguments with colon char? Do i need to use some escaping?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to pass `'--filters={"id":4}'` (in PHP 7.0; if you want to test right now, you'll need to compile it yourself.)